# Android - Selecting a Radio Button in a group causes another Radio Button in another group to be selected

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, android-studio

I am using a fragment layout to display a row in a ListView and I'm using a ListAdapter to populate the ListView. Each row contains a TextView and a RadioGroup, each radio group contains 2 RadioButtons for yes and no.

The problem is that when I run the application, when I select a RadioButton (like yes) on the first group it causes another RadioButton (also yes) to be selected in another group in another row of the ListView.

Here is the layout code for the row fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/questionTextView">

<TextView
    android:text="Dis one na question wey go need yes or no answer?"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/questionView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/customRadioGroup"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/questionView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <RadioButton
        android:text="Yes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/yesRadioBtn"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/noRadioBtn"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/noRadioBtn"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/noRadioBtn"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/noRadioBtn"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp" />

    <RadioButton
        android:text="No"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/noRadioBtn"
        android:layout_below="@+id/questionsTitle"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp" />

</RadioGroup>
```

And my ListAdapter class:

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter {

    private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    private Context context;
    private String[] answers;


    public MyCustomAdapter(ArrayList<String> list, Context context) {
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;
        this.answers = new String[list.size()];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int pos) {
        return list.get(pos);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int pos) {
        //return list.get(pos).getId();
        //just return 0 if your list items do not have an Id variable.
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)     {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
             LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.question_row, null);
        }

        //Handle TextView and display string from your list
        TextView listItemText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.questionView);
        listItemText.setText(list.get(position));

        //Handle buttons and add onClickListeners
        RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup)view.findViewById(R.id.customRadioGroup);
        //radioGroup.setId(position);
        View vYes = radioGroup.getChildAt(0);
        View vNo = radioGroup.getChildAt(1);

        RadioButton yesRadioBtn = (RadioButton)vYes;//(RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.yesRadioBtn);
        RadioButton noRadioBtn = (RadioButton)vNo;//(RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.noRadioBtn);

        yesRadioBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                answers[position] = "yes";
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        noRadioBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                answers[position] = "no";
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    public String[] getAnswers()
    {
        return this.answers;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset the `RadioGroup` if you are reusing a `View` (`convertView != null`). The following change will reset the `RadioGroup` to "no selection", but you will need to set it to the value that is reflected in your internal data structure `answers`.

```
RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup)view.findViewById(R.id.customRadioGroup);
if (convertView != null) {
    radioGroup.clearCheck();
}
```